# Can I use UseCSharpNullComparisonBehavior for a single query?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a query that used to be a stored procedure and was converted to an EF query. It is timing out now. Using SQL Profiler, I can see the only difference in the SQL generated is the new behavior where EF turns `entity.Property == value` into `(entity.Property = @value OR (@value IS NULL AND entity.Property IS NULL))`.

I know I can turn this off for the entire context by setting `UseCSharpNullComparisonBehavior = false`, but I really only want to do it for this one query. Is that possible?

Or, is there a way to write the EF query so it doesn't generate the SQL like this?

Comment: However, can't you just set `context.Configuration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics = true;` before executing the query, and then turning it off after?

Comment: I thought about that, but if another query was ran at the same time, I think it could affect that query as well.

Comment: Not the case. DbContext is specifically NOT to be use for concurrent queries, it will give you all sorts of odd errors if you try.

Comment: I see. I guess I was under the impression that it was a Singleton. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Well it's possible that in your case, your context is a singleton, or that your DI framework doesn't create new ones as required. But if that is the case you should be really careful!

Comment: That worked. I reviewed the code and the context is being instantiated within a UnitOfWork module after it's injected in, so there should be no danger. If you wanted to add your suggestion as an answer I would accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Note, that SQL Server picks up on that SQL pattern and is able to fully utilize indexes. You could try investigating why the query plan changed. It is probably not the complexity of the expression.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set the `UseDatabaseNullSemantics` property of your context to `true`. That is essentially the reverse of the old `ObjectContext.UseCSharpNullComparisonBehavior` property.

```
context.Configuration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics = true;
```

Comment: Just a tip for anyone else doing this, make sure you do a `.ToList()` or something that runs the query _before_ you set it back to false. I was returning `IEnumerable<>` from my function so the query didn't run until I started iterating over it, which was _after_ I set the property back to false. Oops :/

Comment: Good call, there are often intricacies when dealing with deferred execution.